# Отправка email smtp netframework 3.0

Tags: c#

Всем привет, недавно написал отправку на netframework 4.5 все работало ок, но теперь понадобился 3.0, почему то ошибка **SMTP exception** на последней строке, может кто писал на framework 3.0 подскажите плиз.

```
        MailAddress to = new MailAddress ("lala@mail.ru");

        MailAddress from = new MailAddress("lololo@gmail.com");

        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(from, to);

        mail.Subject = "ЧЕЧЕЧЕЧЕЧЕЧ";

        mail.Body = "ЛАЛАЛАЛАЛАЛ";

        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smtp.Port = 587;

        smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(
            "email", "pass");
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        Console.WriteLine("Sending email...");
       try {smtp.Send(mail);} catch (Exception ex)                               {Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)}
```

Сбой при отправке сообщения электронной почты

Comment: Да кстати..и на 4 тоже работает!!!

Comment: @markgenuine, кроме типа исключения напишите ещё, какой Message у этого исключения. Возьмите код в try...catch. SmtpException возникает при "Сбой подключения к серверу SMTP" или "Сбой проверки подлинности" или "Время операции истекло".

Comment: Все равно не работает, пробовал на 3.5 нет фреймворк), не выходит

Comment: @markgenuine, что вы делали? Я вас попросил выложить конкретную ошибку. Отловите исключение с помощью блока try...catch таким образом:
try {smtp.Send(mail);} catch (Exception ex) {Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)}; и выложите в вопрос.

Comment: Дело явно не в версии фреймворка

Comment: Тут же запускаю такой же, даже этот же проект только с использованием 4.5 все работает без проблем...

Comment: Только что запустил этот код сперва на 4.0 версии, после на 3.0 - оба раза успешно отправило письмо! (разумеется изменил логин и пасс предварительно)

Answer (score 2):

Вообщем, есть всего 3 варианта возникновения SmtpException:

1. Сбой подключения к серверу SMTP - неправильно указан сервер, либо нет соединения с ним.
2. Сбой проверки подлинности - неправильно указаны логин/пароль. Может некорректно используется шифрование.
3. Время операции истекло - соединение установлено, но сервер не вернул ответ за время тайм-аута.

Проверьте код по этим параметрам, наверняка найдется ошибка.

Comment: Вот именно что проверял все эти 3 варианта, но к сожалению пока не пришел к успеху, этот же проект я перевожу с использованием фрейма 4.5 и все работает....

Comment: Так в последнем комментарии писали, что получилось. Разве нет?

Comment: Короче...что-то ничего не пойму. Смотрите что у меня получается, только что взял проект, перевел в фрейм 4.5 отправил-пришло, потом в 4 фрейм отправил-пришло, в 3.5,3,2 фремах пробую ошибка:"Сбой при отправке сообщения электронной почты"

Comment: LOL.....проблема была в имени компа....то что там был "-"...
так что в будущем буду реализовывать отправку через сокеты..хоть гемора с именами не будет, всем спасибо за поддержку..